# ui-grid enableCellEditOnFocus scroll problem

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have a ui-grid with `scope.gridOptions = {enableCellEditOnFocus = true}` and about 100 rows and a vertical scroll bar.

If I focus a cell it will enter edit mode, and if I then scroll the grid, it will exit edit mode again, which I guess is expected behavior.

The problem is when I click a cell in the last visible row. Then the auto scroll will scroll down, an then exit the edit mode of the cell i just clicked to edit. This is especially annoying when I'm editting cells with only the keyboard by hitting enter, and reach the cell in the last visible row.

**Is there any way to get around this by making scrolling not exit edit mode?**

Comment: Did you found any workaround for this?